# Android how to get wifi signal strength and connection subType

Tags: android

i i am checking network type by calling this function

```
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo Info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (Info == null || !Info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No connection");
        } else {
            int netType = Info.getType();
            int netSubtype = Info.getSubtype();

            if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Wifi connection");
                //Need to get wifi strength
            } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
              Log.i(TAG, "GPRS/3G connection"); 
               //Need to get differentiate between 3G/GPRS
            } 
        }
```

i do not want to poll wifi strength regularly,but when i do some network stuff i need to check connected wifi strength which i am unable to get.
Secondly when i get netType() as MOBILE how can i determine its 3G/GPRS form netSubType, i mean what are the integer values for 3g/Gprs etc.

Please anyone have idea how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo Info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (Info == null || !Info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No connection");
        } else {
            int netType = Info.getType();
            int netSubtype = Info.getSubtype();

            if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Wifi connection");
             wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                 int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getLinkSpeed();
            //Need to get wifi strength
        } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
          Log.i(TAG, "GPRS/3G connection"); 
           //Need to get differentiate between 3G/GPRS
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and what about differentiating between 3G/GPRS connection types.

Comment: Link speed does not measure the signal strenght. The RSSI does.